# how to add read more/read less after 3 paragraphs inside div with multiple paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This my html code:

```
<div class="page-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dolor risus, tempus eu eros sodales, convallis consequat urna.</p>
    <p> Fusce ut neque sit amet turpis commodo facilisis. Etiam nunc nisi, porta nec ligula nec, cursus sodales orci. </p>
    <p> Cras lacinia odio ut elit pretium blandit. Suspendisse potenti. Ut leo est, pulvinar at urna sed, bibendum vestibulum ligula. </p>
    <p>Mauris efficitur velit in tortor pharetra, ut posuere sapien vulputate. Pellentesque venenatis quam vel suscipit consequat. </p>
    <p>Mauris efficitur velit in tortor pharetra, ut posuere sapien vulputate. Pellentesque venenatis quam vel suscipit consequat. </p>
</div>
```

I want to add read more/read less links after 3rd paragraph tag inside `div`. I can't use any class for `<p>` tag in `html` since all content inside `div` are fetched from `database` with tags.
Can anyone tell me the solution using `css` or `javascript`?

Comment: @15Rabi The question's meaning tells us that the author couldn't find any possible method do it and that's why he/she asked it as a question.

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is pagination.

Comment: You could just fetch say 3 inititially and create a function on click to count them then skip however many are there then append.

Comment: @mitchelangelo *pagination* would hide the first 3 when clicking next "page".   This is *expand/collapse*.   If OP was fetching new rows from DB and appending them (leaving the existing rows) the it would be *add more* - if they did that based on scroll rather than a button, it would be *infinite scroll*

Comment: Paging can be done several different ways such as with infinity scroll, appending data or changing the page. I refer to all of these methods as pagination. If the user has alot of data this is a paging task, depends how many calls he/she is going to make. If data is static then it is expand/collapse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work. It first splits the text based on "`</p>`" to get the paragraphs and then print the top 3 only. And then adds Read More link to it.

```js
var paraHolder = document.getElementsByClassName("page-content")[0];
var readMore = paraHolder.innerHTML;
var para = readMore.split("</p>");
var maxParas = 4;
if (maxParas < para.length - 1) {
  paraHolder.innerHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i <= maxParas - 1; i++) {
    paraHolder.innerHTML += para[i] + "</p>";
  }
  readLess = paraHolder.innerHTML;
  paraHolder.innerHTML += '<a href="#" onclick="readMoreFunction()">Read More...</a>';
}

function readMoreFunction() {
  paraHolder.innerHTML = readMore + '<a href="#" onclick="return readLessFunction()">Read Less...</a>';
}

function readLessFunction() {
  paraHolder.innerHTML = readLess + '<a href="#" onclick="return readMoreFunction()">Read More...</a>'
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dolor risus, tempus eu eros sodales, convallis consequat urna.</p>
  <p> Fusce ut neque sit amet turpis commodo facilisis. Etiam nunc nisi, porta nec ligula nec, cursus sodales orci. </p>
  <p> Cras lacinia odio ut elit pretium blandit. Suspendisse potenti. Ut leo est, pulvinar at urna sed, bibendum vestibulum ligula. </p>
  <p>Mauris efficitur velit in tortor pharetra, ut posuere sapien vulputate. Pellentesque venenatis quam vel suscipit consequat. </p>
  <p>Mauris efficitur velit in tortor pharetra, ut posuere sapien vulputate. Pellentesque venenatis quam vel suscipit consequat. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using mostly CSS (thus reducing FOUC), with some jquery to add a couple of buttons (could be in the html) and to add/remove a class on the wrapper `.page-content`.

```js
$("<button class='more'>read more...</button>")
  .appendTo(".page-content")
  .click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".page-content").removeClass("collapsed");
  });
$("<button class='less'>read less...</button>")
  .appendTo(".page-content")
  .click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".page-content").addClass("collapsed");
  });
```

```css
.page-content.collapsed > :nth-of-type(n+4) {
  display:none;
}

.page-content > .more {
  display:none;
}
.page-content > .less {
  display:block;
}

.page-content.collapsed > .more {
  display:block;
}
.page-content.collapsed > .less {
  display:none;
}


/* style as "link" */
.page-content > button {
  background: none!important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0!important;
  color: #069;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content collapsed">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dolor risus, tempus eu eros sodales, convallis consequat urna.</p>
    <p> Fusce ut neque sit amet turpis commodo facilisis. Etiam nunc nisi, porta nec ligula nec, cursus sodales orci. </p>
    <p> Cras lacinia odio ut elit pretium blandit. Suspendisse potenti. Ut leo est, pulvinar at urna sed, bibendum vestibulum ligula. </p>
    <p>Mauris efficitur velit in tortor pharetra, ut posuere sapien vulputate. Pellentesque venenatis quam vel suscipit consequat. </p>
    <p>Mauris efficitur velit in tortor pharetra, ut posuere sapien vulputate. Pellentesque venenatis quam vel suscipit consequat. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a collapsable section with pure HTML...

```
<details>
  <summary>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dolor risus, tempus eu eros sodales, convallis consequat urna.</p>
    <p> Fusce ut neque sit amet turpis commodo facilisis. Etiam nunc nisi, porta nec ligula nec, cursus sodales orci. </p>
    <p> Cras lacinia odio ut elit pretium blandit. Suspendisse potenti. Ut leo est, pulvinar at urna sed, bibendum vestibulum ligula. </p>
    <label class="label" id="read-more">Read more</label>
  </summary>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dolor risus, tempus eu eros sodales, convallis consequat urna.</p>
  <p> Fusce ut neque sit amet turpis commodo facilisis. Etiam nunc nisi, porta nec ligula nec, cursus sodales orci. </p>
  <p> Cras lacinia odio ut elit pretium blandit. Suspendisse potenti. Ut leo est, pulvinar at urna sed, bibendum vestibulum ligula. </p>
  <label class="label" id="read-less">Read less</label>
</details>
```

Add an event listener for label control...

```
details.addEventListener("toggle", event => {
  if (details.open) {
    /* the element was toggled open */
     $("#read-more").hide();
  } else {
    /* the element was toggled closed */
     $("#read-more").show();
  }
});
```

Add some style...

```
.label {
   text-align: right;
   font-size: 9px;
   display: block;
}
```