# Append div 10 times each time button clicked using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('<button class="btn more">View More</button>')
         .appendTo(".listing-item-container")
         .click(function() {
            $(this).closest(".listing-item-container").removeClass("collapsed");
          });
          $('<button class="btn less">View Less</button>')
         .appendTo(".listing-item-container")
         .click(function() {
           $(this).closest(".listing-item-container").addClass("collapsed");
         });
      });
```

```css
.listing-item-container.collapsed > :nth-of-type(n+3) {
      display:none;
    }
    
    .listing-item-container > .more {
      display:none;
    }
    .listing-item-container > .less {
      display:block;
    }
    
    .listing-item-container.collapsed > .more {
      display:block;
    }
    .listing-item-container.collapsed > .less {
      display:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listing-item-container collapsed">
        <div class="listing-item">
            <p>FEATURES</p>
            <ul class="no-list-style">
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="listing-item">
            <p>FEATURES</p>
            <ul class="no-list-style">
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="listing-item">
            <p>FEATURES</p>
            <ul class="no-list-style">
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
            </ul>
        </div><div class="listing-item">
            <p>FEATURES</p>
            <ul class="no-list-style">
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="listing-item">
            <p>FEATURES</p>
            <ul class="no-list-style">
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
                <li>list content</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--  100 more listing-item divs present here   -->
    </div>
```

In above code when I click `view more`, it will display all remaining 'listing item' `div` and when I click `view less`, all `divs` are collapsed and display only 2 `divs`.

My expected output is, when I click `view more` it should only display next 2 'listing item' `div` and `view more` button. Again If I click `view more`, it should display next 2 'listing item' `div`  and `view more` button. This should continue for all 100 more 'listing item' `div`. In the end it should display `view less` button. When I click `view less` button, each time it should collapse last 2 'listing item' `div`.

How can I modify my code to get the expected output?

Comment: You should be doing this with the native <details> element

Comment: Yes I understand that now 

Comment: I thought that code looked familiar... https://stackoverflow.com/a/71628196/2181514   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is in the use of [jquery slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) (same as javascript slice() but on a jquery collection).

```
var howManyItemsToShow = 2;
$(".listing-item").hide().slice(howManyItemsToShow).show();
```

this will hide all the items, then show the first 2.  The UI update will be combined into a single action.  If you add animation (.slideDown / .fadeIn) then this will need to be different.

You then add your "pagesize" (2 in the example) each time you click; and update.

Add a check for start/end and utilising the [css trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71628196/2181514) to show/hide the more/less buttons gives you:

```js
var lines = 2;
var pagesize = 2;

// assuming they don't change, load them up-front for small efficiency gain (and DRY)
var items = $(".listing-item-container .listing-item");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('<button class="btn more">View More</button>')
    .appendTo(".listing-item-container")
    .click(function() {
    
      lines += pagesize;
      items
        .show()
        .slice(lines).hide();
        
      if (lines >= items.length)
        $(this).closest(".listing-item-container").removeClass("collapsed");
    });

  $('<button class="btn less">View Less</button>')
    .appendTo(".listing-item-container")
    .click(function() {
      // same for "less" but -= and different check
      // this can of course be combined with the "more" button (DRY)
      // shown separately for clarity
      lines -= pagesize;
      items.show();
      items.slice(lines).hide();
      if (lines <= pagesize)
        $(this).closest(".listing-item-container").addClass("collapsed");
    });
});
```

```css
.listing-item-container.collapsed> :nth-of-type(n+3) {
  display: none;
}

.listing-item-container>.more {
  display: none;
}

.listing-item-container>.less {
  display: block;
}

.listing-item-container.collapsed>.more {
  display: block;
}

.listing-item-container.collapsed>.less {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listing-item-container collapsed">
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul class="no-list-style">
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul class="no-list-style">
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul class="no-list-style">
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul class="no-list-style">
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul class="no-list-style">
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
      <li>list content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--  100 more listing-item divs present here   -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do that this way...

```js
((parentRef='.listing-item-container', ItemsRef='.listing-item', startView=2, addView=2 )=>
 {
  const
    listItems  = document.querySelectorAll(ItemsRef)
  , btMoreLess = document.querySelector(parentRef).appendChild( document.createElement('button'))
    ;
  btMoreLess.className = 'showMore'

  var listItemsViewCount = startView -addView;

  btMoreLess.onclick =_=>
    {
    listItemsViewCount += btMoreLess.classList.contains('Less') ? -addView : +addView
    listItems.forEach( (item,i)=> item.classList.toggle('noDisplay',i>=listItemsViewCount) )

    if (listItemsViewCount >= listItems.length)  btMoreLess.classList.add('Less')
    else if (listItemsViewCount === startView)   btMoreLess.classList.remove('Less')
    }

  btMoreLess.click()  // init
  }
)() // IIFE ending
```

```css
.noDisplay{ display:none; } 
button.showMore:before { content : 'View More'; }
button.showMore.Less:before { content : 'View Less'; }

.listing-item-container   { counter-reset: itemCounter;         }
.listing-item             { counter-increment: itemCounter;     }
.listing-item > p::before { content: counter(itemCounter) '.';  }
```

```html
<div class="listing-item-container">
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item">
    <p>FEATURES</p>
    <ul> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> <li>list content</li> </ul>
  </div>
  <!--  100 more listing-item divs present here   -->
</div>
```